# How to place 2 dynamic width UILabel to a view with Masonry constraints?

Tags: ios, masonry, ios-autolayout

I really liked Masonry library. It saves me from the conflicts of Apple's Autolayout.

I solve most of my problems with this library. But there is one thing I couldn't achieved.

There are 2 labels in same UIView. Both labels have dynamic width. I wrote this code and problems occured

```
   [self.nameLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.bottomContainer.centerY);
        make.left.equalTo(self.left).with.offset(@10);
        make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@120);
        make.leading.equalTo(self.priceLabel.trailing);
    }];

    [self.priceLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.bottomContainer.centerY);
        make.right.equalTo(self.right).with.offset(@-10);
        make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(@150);
    }];
```

[image: Problem]

What should I do to avoid this kind of problems?

Comment: You need to play with priorities and minimum values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
    [self.nameLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.bottomContainer.centerY);
        make.left.equalTo(self.left).with.offset(@10);
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.priceLabel.leading);
    }];

    [self.priceLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.bottomContainer.centerY);
        make.right.equalTo(self.right).with.offset(@-10);
    }];


    [self.priceLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.nameLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Thank you